# GMLib Rad Studio 10 Seattle - Delphi - Android

Tags: android, google-maps, delphi, mobile, gmlib

I just picked up Delphi not long ago so I'm **really** new to it. I was just wondering if GM Lib works with Rad Studio 10?

Also, I'm a little puzzled about installing GM Lib, seems like when I try to follow the instructions in "Install.txt", I couldn't compile "GMLib_D-Seattle10_VCL" or "_FMX". Would produce an error to it.

I'm trying to create an application for Android that integrates with Google Maps, like having a "LISTING" in the Application would immediately show it in the Google Maps View. Also, clustering markers if the MapView is too zoomed out.

I've been doing a lot of reading but it seems like the curve is really steep, couldn't really find a way before I stumbled on GMLib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GMLib library for Delphi does not support the mobile platforms. This article (http://www.fmxexpress.com/extensive-google-maps-api-library-for-delphi-xe6-firemonkey-on-windows/) suggests WebGMaps from TMS for mobile platforms.

Comment: But WebGMaps isn't free right? Are there any free options? Is it possible to pull this off without any extra components like GMLib or WebGMaps? Just by using the provided components listed here: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/FMX.Maps

Comment: The question you asked was about GMLib. Of course you can build your own code to do the same. Or adapt GMLib. Price isn't really relevant to the question. Anyway, I think I answered the question you asked. If you want to turn this into a recommendation question that's off topic at this site.